# Disapearing features after specific zoom degree in ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, features, zoom

I have faced a Problem during my Analysis. I have some Polygon Features and after up to specific degree they would be disapeared.

I have checked all the Setting and no zoom degree in defined.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Have you run a Check Geometry or Repair Geometry on the file to ensure that there are no errors in it?  Also ensure that there are zoom levels/visibilities set on the file

Comment: thx for your reply. Well, actually I have done the 'Repair Geometry' and no zoom Level is set on the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Shapefile, the Spatial Index probably needs to be updated. The Spatial Index on a File Geodatabase feature class is automatically updated.

Comment: You might just import into a FGDB and see if that solves it. One can always export it back out as a shapefile (if indeed shapefile is what's needed).